# Write error to ble characteristics in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I tried to write to ble characteristics.But the return error is "Writing is not permitted".

This is to discover the characteristics.
// Invoked when you discover the characteristics of a specified service.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_SERVICE_UUID]])  {
        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics)
        {
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:dev2appcharacteristicsUUID]) {
                [devicePeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Found R-Motion device with characteristics: %@\n", aChar);
                dev2appCharacteristic = aChar;
            }
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:app2devcharacteristicsUUID]) {
                //[devicePeripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Found R-Motion device with characteristics: %@\n", aChar);
                app2devCharacteristic = aChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can discover correctly. And trying to write to app2devCharacteristic.
It has `_properties unsigned long long  4` and `_isNotifying    bool    false`.

I tried to write Byte array as

```
- (IBAction)RequestResult:(id)sender {
    unsigned char bytes[] = {0x00, 0xCC, 0xFF};//{0xFF, 0xCC, 0x00};//
    NSData *transactData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:3];
    [devicePeripheral writeValue:transactData forCharacteristic:app2devCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

}
```

I have return at `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` with error `"Writing is not permitted"`

If I changed to withoutresponse as

```
- (IBAction)RequestResult:(id)sender {
    unsigned char bytes[] = {0x00, 0xCC, 0xFF};//{0xFF, 0xCC, 0x00};//
    NSData *transactData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:3];
    [devicePeripheral writeValue:transactData forCharacteristic:app2devCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];

}
```

There is no error returned. But my peripheral doesn't receive anything.

Comment: You said that `_properties unsigned long long  4` is for `app2devCharacteristic`. Well, `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04,` So you clearly can't do `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` in the `type` of `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`. For the rest (not being written), how do you know that? Is `transactData` valid?  Does your device really expects that?

Answer (score 0):

The peripheral sets permissions for each characteristic. Read and write permissions are separate. Write not permitted simply means that you are not allowed to write to it, regardless of encryption level.

If you use write without response, no error message will be delivered, per specification.

Edit: hmm assuming _properties refer to the Characteristic Properties table in the Bluetooth Core spec, Vol 3 Part G section 3.3.1.1 a 4 means that Write without response should be allowed but not Write with response.